# Magento2: How can I access Zend\Stdlib\Parameters Object array?

Tags: magento2, array, object

I have below result:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($data); die();
```

> Result

```
Zend\Stdlib\Parameters Object
(
    [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
        (
            [success_url] =>  
            [error_url] =>  
            [company_name] => fdgdg
            [name] =>  fgfdg
            [email] => 
            [telephone] =>  dfgdf
            [address] =>  gdfg
            [city] =>  
            [state] =>  
            [zipcode] =>  
            [industry] =>  
            [how_did_you_here] =>  
        )

)
```

I want to access only array?

Comment: I got the answer.  get_object_vars($data)

Comment: Please add this as an answer and accept it so other may get help @Ravi

Answer (score 0):

I used below php function:

```
 get_object_vars($data);
```